# Alterar link do Logo do meu blog wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Boa tarde galera!, a situação é a seguinte, eu tenho um site feito em PHP com um CMS de uma outra agência que fez para o meu cliente. Agora eu estou gerenciando o site dele, e ele me pediu um blog. Eu instalei o Wordpress dentro do public_html do site dele e fiz o blog. Só que o link da Logo do blog está redirecionando para o próprio blog (porque o Wordpress acha que o blog é a pagina inicial) como eu altero esse link para redirecionar para a verdadeira página inicial do blog ? Procurei em todos os arquivos possíveis do Wordpress e não encontrei. :(

Valeu pela ajuda e atenção de todos desde já :)

Comment: tenta algumas coisas com esse link: https://wiki.infolink.com.br/Alterando_URL_do_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

use esse plugin, espero ter ajudado, da um up ai na resposta, abraço.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/smntcs-custom-logo-link/
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]